# Test package behaviour when suggested dependency is not installed with testthat

Tags: r, testing, dependencies, r-package, testthat

I have a package with a suggested dependency enabling optional behaviour.

Following the best practice, I added this dependency in my "Suggests" and check if it's installed with `requireNamespace` before using it.

In this particular case, the suggested package is `data.tree` and the optional behaviour is making a pretty print instead of a more boring one.

```
myfun <- function(...) {
  if (requireNamespace("data.tree", quietly = TRUE)) {
    # do pretty print
  } else {
    # do boring print
  }
}
```

My question is: how do I test this behaviour with `testthat`? I want to test both branches of the `if/else`, but since I do have data.tree installed, I only ever run the first branch.

```
test_that("myfun does a pretty print with data.tree", {
  myfun()
})

test_that("myfun does a boring print if data.tree is not installed", {
  # Ideally I am looking for a bit of code like this: 
  with(simulate_missing("data.tree"), 
       myfun())
})
```

Is there a way to simulate a missing dependency with `testthat`, or more generally a way to test `myfun`?

Comment: One possibility would be to create two different library folders. One could have the `data.tree` package and one would not, and you can just run the code using the different `.libPaths()`. The `withr::with_libpaths` can help set/unset those values.